# IN-Condition type cast seems wrong

Tags: oracle

I have a table with the columne `ErrorID`. For historical reasons this ID is of Tye `VARCHAR2 (30 CHAR)` and encodes the kind of error occured during an application's runtime.

```
ErrorID | Meaning
------------------------
01      | no error
02      | wrong password
...
99      | unknown
ERROR   | unknown
```

To check, if critical errors have occured, I use the following query:

```
SELECT ThreadID, CASE WHEN ErrorID IN ('05','06') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END AS "Critical"
FROM ErrorTable
```

The result is always `No`. If I change the query to

```
SELECT ThreadID, CASE WHEN ErrorID IN (05, 06) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END AS "Critical"
FROM ErrorTable
```

The result is correct, i.e., `Yes` and `No` at the right thread.

I have read, that Oracle will cast `'10'` to `NUMBER` datatype, if it appears in a numeric expression, but in my case, `ErrorID` is a `VARCHAR2` which can be a real string (see last entry in the example table).

Why does Oracle behave like this? I think it is very dangerously, cause I told my customer "no critical errors accoured during the test", although they did...

**UPDATE**
As wished in the comments, here the actual output. Due to data protection laws, limited the columns of interest:

```
DESC ErrorTable
Name                         Null     Typ                 
---------------------------- -------- ------------------- 
ThreadID                     NOT NULL NUMBER(38)          
...
ErrorID                               VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) 

SELECT * FROM ErrorTable WHERE ThreadID = 8917
THREADID | ... | ERRORID
------------------------
8917     | ... | 01 

SELECT ThreadID, CASE WHEN ErrorID IN ('1','01') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS "Critical" FROM ErrorTable WHERE ThreadID = 8917;
THREADID | CRITICAL
--------------------
8917     | No  

SELECT ThreadID, CASE WHEN ErrorID IN (01) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS "Critical" FROM ErrorTable WHERE ThreadID = 8917;
THREADID | CRITICAL
------------------------
8917     | Yes
```

Comment: Are you sure there is _always_ al leading zero? Because comparing '5' IN ('05', '06') will return false while '5' IN ('5', '6') will return true.

Comment: Yes, there is. `SELECT * FROM ErrorTable` shows always the leading 0. Also a change to `ErrorID IN ('5','6')` returns always `No`

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? I've made a simple test, and it worked for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09e90/1

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle database does not behave as you assert. `in ('05', '06')` will match the pertinent rows. `in (05, 06)`  will hurl ORA-01722 because  `'ERROR'` cannot be cast to a number.

The most likely explanation is that the ERROR ID is not what you think it is. Perhaps you have trailing spaces? `'05 ' != '05'`. Although you should still get the ORA-01722 error.

---

If this doesn't help you need to post a reproducible test case: table structure, sample data, a query which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You were totally right!!! The ErrorID was '01 ' (with space). This couldn't be seen in the SQLDeveloper output and is a dreadful database design... ORA-01722 was not thrown, since the `ERROR` ID did not appear in the current data. Thank you very much.